# In Jmeter distributed (remote) testing, is it possible to store results file on remote server?

Tags: jmeter

I was using non-GUI option to perform a distributed load testing with Jmeter from master server A (Linux) to slave server B (Linux). Here's what I did:

```
./jmeter -n -t xxx.jmx -l results.log -R xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

By default, Jmeter will write the results file to the master server A. I'm wondering if there's a way to directly store the results file on remote server B.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The idea is they are dumb slaves, possibly without even the means to store data locally.  The methods are invoked on a remote processor (RMI) and run from there, but all other resources are kept at the client side.

You could set up a CI server like Jenkins to run jmeter clients in a distributed manner. That will allow you more control over how tests are distributed.  I have a jenkins set up that runs jmeter client on a master, with distributed tests to remote (jmeter) slaves, which are also jenkins slaves, tied to jobs that control the workspaces.  This means they are never used by jenkins, but jenkins can get results files out of the workspace, aggregate them, and produce graphs using jmeter plugins CMDrunner.

The other possibility is to prefix your sample results with the unique part of the IP address of the current slave.  This will allow you to display them aggregated or separately in your results viewer, and potentially write scripts to separate the results out and store them back on the slave they came from.

You could also use samba or similar to share the remote slave drive, and store the results directly there from the master.

If you have only one slave, any of these would be easy to implement, but get more complex as you add more slaves.

Answer (score 0):

Look at sample sender alternative implementations.

Read the concerned paragraph here:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html

Natively it works like this, an option is not to use distributed mode and run many jmeter instances in non gui mode.

Try jmeter user mailing list and if you don't get an answer maybe open a bugzilla enhancement request.

Comment: Thanks PMD. I read it, but it seems to me that they are only the alternatives to sending the result back to master server. Still no explanation for how to keep result on remote server. Correct me if I misunderstood it.

Comment: I added enhancement request for this - https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59012

Answer (score -3):

If you want to build distributed load testing system you can try use [Jagger](https://jagger.griddynamics.net/)

Comment: Not a constructive answer.